# errors while i reopen project in visual studio 2012 Ultimate

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2012, themes

The problem starts from 3 weeks. I was building project using visual studio and i used visual basic.
i saved the project without any error, but when i reopened the project again it's didn't able me to see the forms and get 6 errors and 3 messages.

i was using theme and the theme not have any bug, because i was using it without any problem
and all people used it. they called the theme (YouTube Theme)

The Errors:

Message 1

```
Could not find type 'YouTube_Downloader.YTTheme'.  Please make sure that the assembly that contains this type is referenced.  If this type is a part of your development project, make sure that the project has been successfully built using settings for your current platform or Any CPU.   
0   0
```

Message 2

```
Could not find type 'YouTube_Downloader.YTButton'.  Please make sure that the assembly that contains this type is referenced.  If this type is a part of your development project, make sure that the project has been successfully built using settings for your current platform or Any CPU.
    0   0
```

Message 3

```
The variable 'YtTheme1' is either undeclared or was never assigned. C:\Users\Home\documents\visual studio 2012\Projects\YouTube Downloader\YouTube Downloader\AboutBox.Designer.vb  107 0
```

Error   4

```
Unable to open module file 'C:\Users\Home\AppData\Local\Temp\.NETFramework,Version=v4.5.AssemblyAttributes.vb': System Error &H80070002&    C:\Users\Home\AppData\Local\Temp\.NETFramework,Version=v4.5.AssemblyAttributes.vb   1   1   YouTube Downloader
```

Error   5

```
Handles clause requires a WithEvents variable defined in the containing type or one of its base types.  C:\Users\Home\documents\visual studio 2012\Projects\YouTube Downloader\YouTube Downloader\YouTubeDownloader.vb  18  73  YouTube Downloader
```

Error   6

```
Handles clause requires a WithEvents variable defined in the containing type or one of its base types.  C:\Users\Home\documents\visual studio 2012\Projects\YouTube Downloader\YouTube Downloader\YouTubeDownloader.vb  24  73  YouTube Downloader
```

Error   7

```
Handles clause requires a WithEvents variable defined in the containing type or one of its base types.  C:\Users\Home\documents\visual studio 2012\Projects\YouTube Downloader\YouTube Downloader\YouTubeDownloader.vb  28  73  YouTube Downloader
```

Error   8

```
Handles clause requires a WithEvents variable defined in the containing type or one of its base types.  C:\Users\Home\documents\visual studio 2012\Projects\YouTube Downloader\YouTube Downloader\YouTubeDownloader.vb  32  75  YouTube Downloader
```

Error   9

```
Handles clause requires a WithEvents variable defined in the containing type or one of its base types.  C:\Users\Home\documents\visual studio 2012\Projects\YouTube Downloader\YouTube Downloader\YouTubeDownloader.vb  74  75  YouTube Downloader
```

when i opened the project it's not show me the form design 
i added picture for my problem
 [URL=http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/7/9gam.png/][IMG]http://img7.imageshack.us/img7/457/9gam.png[/IMG][/URL]

http://img7.imageshack.us/img7/457/9gam.png

please help !!

The problem didn't was and there are problem when i use (Ghost Theme) it's giving me 25 errors and 1 warning.

The errors:

Error   1

```
Option Strict On disallows implicit conversions from 'Integer' to 'UInteger'.   C:\Users\Home\AppData\Local\Temporary Projects\GhostTheme\Class1.vb 1909    34  GhostTheme
```

Error   2

```
Option Strict On disallows implicit conversions from 'Double' to 'Integer'. C:\Users\Home\AppData\Local\Temporary Projects\GhostTheme\Class1.vb 2216    75  GhostTheme
```

Error   3

```
Option Strict On disallows implicit conversions from 'Double' to 'Integer'. C:\Users\Home\AppData\Local\Temporary Projects\GhostTheme\Class1.vb 2226    75  GhostTheme
```

Error   4

```
Option Strict On disallows implicit conversions from 'Double' to 'Integer'. C:\Users\Home\AppData\Local\Temporary Projects\GhostTheme\Class1.vb 2236    75  GhostTheme
```

Error   5

```
Option Strict On disallows implicit conversions from 'Double' to 'Integer'. C:\Users\Home\AppData\Local\Temporary Projects\GhostTheme\Class1.vb 2313    91  GhostTheme
```

Error   6

```
Option Strict On disallows implicit conversions from 'Single' to 'Integer'. C:\Users\Home\AppData\Local\Temporary Projects\GhostTheme\Class1.vb 2363    20  GhostTheme
```

Error   7

```
Option Strict On disallows implicit conversions from 'System.Drawing.Point' to 'System.Drawing.Size'.   C:\Users\Home\AppData\Local\Temporary Projects\GhostTheme\Class1.vb 2419    19  GhostTheme
```

Error   8

```
Option Strict On disallows implicit conversions from 'Single' to 'Integer'. C:\Users\Home\AppData\Local\Temporary Projects\GhostTheme\Class1.vb 2475    20  GhostTheme
```

Error   9

```
Option Strict On disallows implicit conversions from 'System.Drawing.Point' to 'System.Drawing.Size'.   C:\Users\Home\AppData\Local\Temporary Projects\GhostTheme\Class1.vb 2512    19  GhostTheme
```

Error   10

```
Option Strict On disallows implicit conversions from 'Single' to 'Integer'. C:\Users\Home\AppData\Local\Temporary Projects\GhostTheme\Class1.vb 2538    33  GhostTheme
```

Error   11

```
Option Strict On disallows implicit conversions from 'Single' to 'Integer'. C:\Users\Home\AppData\Local\Temporary Projects\GhostTheme\Class1.vb 2574    107 GhostTheme
```

Error   12

```
Option Strict On disallows implicit conversions from 'Single' to 'Integer'. C:\Users\Home\AppData\Local\Temporary Projects\GhostTheme\Class1.vb 2585    28  GhostTheme
```

Error   13

```
Option Strict On disallows implicit conversions from 'Single' to 'Integer'. C:\Users\Home\AppData\Local\Temporary Projects\GhostTheme\Class1.vb 2587    13  GhostTheme
```

Error   14

```
Option Strict On disallows implicit conversions from 'Object' to 'System.Drawing.Image'.    C:\Users\Home\AppData\Local\Temporary Projects\GhostTheme\Class1.vb 2601    30  GhostTheme
```

Warning 15

```
property 'ForeColor' shadows an overridable method in the base class 'TabControl'. To override the base method, this method must be declared 'Overrides'.   C:\Users\Home\AppData\Local\Temporary Projects\GhostTheme\Class1.vb 2614    21  GhostTheme
```

Error   16

```
Option Strict On disallows implicit conversions from 'Object' to 'System.Drawing.Image'.    C:\Users\Home\AppData\Local\Temporary Projects\GhostTheme\Class1.vb 2689    30  GhostTheme
```

Error   17

```
Option Strict On disallows implicit conversions from 'Object' to 'String'.  C:\Users\Home\AppData\Local\Temporary Projects\GhostTheme\Class1.vb 2714    20  GhostTheme
```

Error   18

```
Option Strict On disallows implicit conversions from 'Double' to 'Integer'. C:\Users\Home\AppData\Local\Temporary Projects\GhostTheme\Class1.vb 2754    81  GhostTheme
```

Error   19

```
Option Strict On disallows implicit conversions from 'Double' to 'Integer'. C:\Users\Home\AppData\Local\Temporary Projects\GhostTheme\Class1.vb 2805    85  GhostTheme
```

Error   20

```
Option Strict On disallows implicit conversions from 'Double' to 'Integer'. C:\Users\Home\AppData\Local\Temporary Projects\GhostTheme\Class1.vb 2858    103 GhostTheme
```

Error   21

```
Option Strict On disallows implicit conversions from 'Double' to 'Integer'. C:\Users\Home\AppData\Local\Temporary Projects\GhostTheme\Class1.vb 2859    67  GhostTheme
```

Error   22

```
Option Strict On disallows implicit conversions from 'Single' to 'Integer'. C:\Users\Home\AppData\Local\Temporary Projects\GhostTheme\Class1.vb 2864    29  GhostTheme
```

Error   23

```
Option Strict On disallows implicit conversions from 'Object' to 'String'.  C:\Users\Home\AppData\Local\Temporary Projects\GhostTheme\Class1.vb 2866    26  GhostTheme
```

Error   24

```
Option Strict On disallows implicit conversions from 'Object' to 'String'.  C:\Users\Home\AppData\Local\Temporary Projects\GhostTheme\Class1.vb 2869    30  GhostTheme
```

Error   25

```
Option Strict On disallows implicit conversions from 'Object' to 'System.Drawing.Image'.    C:\Users\Home\AppData\Local\Temporary Projects\GhostTheme\Class1.vb 2890    30  GhostTheme
```

Error   26

```
Option Strict On disallows implicit conversions from 'Double' to 'Integer'. C:\Users\Home\AppData\Local\Temporary Projects\GhostTheme\Class1.vb 2906    81  GhostTheme
```

i add picture too about it.

http://im36.gulfup.com/0OcH9.bmp

[url=http://www.gulfup.com/?0RKgoK][img]http://im36.gulfup.com/0OcH9.bmp[/img][/url]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I such cases there is usually only one error causing all others. It is difficult to find where the problem is without careful searching thorough the code.

The advice is:

1. Create a new empty project.
2. Gradually and carefully transfer the code from old (corrupt) project
   to new one either file by file or even line by line.
3. When the error appears you have a solution. When the error does not
   appear you are facing internal problem of VS but still the problem
   is solved.

Alternatively you can try other way round:

1. Make a copy of your project.
2. Delete files or lines till the error disappear.
3. The problem line will be identified and you have a solution.

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

I tried this before i post here ..
and it's didn't work, for example: (GhostTheme) i was adding it to class without any error and as you see above it's giving me 25 error and some messages

as well as old project

> The advice is:
>
> Create a new empty project. Gradually and carefully transfer the code
>   from old (corrupt) project to new one either file by file or even line
>   by line. When the error appears you have a solution. When the error
>   does not appear you are facing internal problem of VS but still the
>   problem is solved.

i did it before, but when i save it and re open the project it's tell me about errors

so i think the only way and the last way is to format my PC and re install all things, Because the problem didn't was before and after formatting my PC i think it will be done